# URL in get parameters returns page not found error

Tags: php, wordpress, timthumb

I am trying to use timthumb.php for image processing on my site. When I try to pass image url to timthumb.php using:
`<img src="'.home_url().'/timthumb.php?src='.$image_attributes[0].'&w=200"/>`
It returns page not found error.

`$image_attributes[0]` is the **absolute URL** of the image.

When I logged in using any user account, it works perfectly but for non-logged in users it returns page not found error.

if I pass anything else except URl or if I remove `http://`, it returns without any issue. I need to pass image URL so that I can generate thumbnails but its not working for only guest users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the absolute url not passing as a parameter, so there was nothing wrong with timthum. I just changed the url by converting some character of the url while passing by using str_replace() and again, I changed back the passed parameter to url in timthumb.php. Now it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

> **set your file path using 'template_directory url'**

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>&h=126&w=330&zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="330" height="126" />
```